# Barycentric subdivision

Tags: algebraic-topology

Could sb tell me the proof that making barycentric subdivision twice of a polyhedron always gives a regular triangulation with tetrahedon faces? (This is not true with just one barycentric subdivision, it has to be TWICE!!. And a counterexample of the last?). Thank you very much!

Comment: Also asked here, simultaneously: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/193744/barycentric-subdivision

Comment: This could be useful: http://tarunchitra.com/papers/6510/hw8.pdf (see page 5).